# Get the latest date only on a SQL server query involving multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm a student and new in SQL. I'm working with a database that concern the formation of people. Some formation have to been done again before a specific date limit (some are every 24 months top, or every 36 months top) but can be done again before if wanted. I need a query that shows every persons who has to be "recycled" (means they have to follow again the formation in xxx days). I managed to done it but my query always shows all the formation they've done but I only need the most recent one in order to calculate properly when they have to be "recycled":

Here's my query:

```
select ATR_NOM as 'Last name',
       ATR_PRENOM as 'First name',
       TME_LIBELLE as 'Session',
       TME_ID as 'Session ID',
       SSN_DATE_DEBUT as 'Begenning formation date',
       TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI as 'Recycling limit in month',
       DATEADD(mm, TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI, SSN_DATE_DEBUT) as 'Date limit for recycling'


from INSCRIPTION
join SESSION on SSN_ID = INS_SSN_ID
join ACTEUR on INS_ATR_ID = ATR_ID
join THEME on SSN_TME_ID = TME_ID

--Only formation that requires recycling
where TME_RECYCLAGE_ACTIF =1

--Only after the current day
and DATEADD(mm, TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI, SSN_DATE_DEBUT) > SYSDATETIME()

order by ATR_NOM
```

And I get:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pnU7.jpg)

But look at line 2 and 3: the same person did the same session twice, in 2017 and 2018. I don't want the 2017 to appear because the recycling has already been done in 2018. I want only the 2018 result (line 3) to appear, but I can't figure out how to do that. And this goes for all the persons in the DB, not only this person.

Answer (score 1):

use window function `row_number()`(most dbms support window function)

```
    with cte 
    (
    select ATR_NOM as 'Last name',
           ATR_PRENOM as 'First name',
           TME_LIBELLE as 'Session',
           TME_ID as 'Session ID',
           SSN_DATE_DEBUT as 'Begenning formation date',
           TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI as 'Recycling limit in month',
           DATEADD(mm, TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI, SSN_DATE_DEBUT) as 'Date limit for recycling',
 row_number() over(parition by ATR_NOM,ATR_PRENOM,TME_LIBELLE,TME_ID
                  order by SSN_DATE_DEBUT desc)rn


    from INSCRIPTION
    join SESSION on SSN_ID = INS_SSN_ID
    join ACTEUR on INS_ATR_ID = ATR_ID
    join THEME on SSN_TME_ID = TME_ID

    --Only formation that requires recycling
    where TME_RECYCLAGE_ACTIF =1

    --Only after the current day
    and DATEADD(mm, TME_RECYCLAGE_DELAI, SSN_DATE_DEBUT) > SYSDATETIME()


    ) select * from cte where rn=1
```